# How to check a icon is changed in UIAutomator (enabled/disabled WiFi)

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to check if the icon is changed when I enabled/disabled WiFi.
I have a app that enabled and disabled WiFi but I don`t know how can I verify if this is enabled or disabled. (Only the icon is changed when is enabled Wifi - will be white, and when is disabled - will be grey).
 Anyone can help me with a answer how can I verify if a icon is changed when I enabled/disabled WiFi?
 This I want to used for another icons (like RDS for radio app, RDS icon is changed when RDS is active or is grey when RDS is not active).

Answer (score 0):

Use the uiautomatorviewer and check the icon properties. There is no exact answer but there will be differences when you compare the active (white) and disabled (grey) buttons propertiesand just put the uiautomator to check for that one specific property

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer but the icon properties remain the same when WiFi is enabled or disabled (all prop. are the same: checkable, checked, clickable, enabled, focusable, focused, etc) this is why I ask if anyone try and found a solution to check if a icon image (ImageView) is changed.